# Html table: last column width auto

Tags: html, css, layout, html-table

I have this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/dQNqBz?editors=1100). 
I would like that

a) table fill the parent in width
  b) last column to fill the empty space
  c) column a and column b fixed (100 & 200)px

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

td {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

th:nth-child(2);
td:nth-child(2) {
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
}

th:nth-child(1),
td:nth-child(1) {
  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
}

thead,
tbody>tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

tbody>tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 red">
  hello
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id (100px)</th>
        <th>Name (200px)</th>
        <th>Description (auto)</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>654</td>
      <td>987</td>
      <td>this is a description</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>963</td>
      <td>147</td>
      <td>this is the second description</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>753</td>
      <td>951</td>
      <td>this is the third description</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: what type of issues are you facing. and please clear that you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `width` instead of `max-width` and `min-width` and you got an `;` instead of `,` in the second column rule.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}

td {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

th:nth-child(2),
td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 200px;
}

th:nth-child(1),
td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 100px;
}

thead,
tbody>tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

tbody>tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 red">
  hello
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Id (100px)</th>
        <th>Name (200px)</th>
        <th>Description (auto)</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <td>654</td>
      <td>987</td>
      <td>this is a description</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>963</td>
      <td>147</td>
      <td>this is the second description</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>753</td>
      <td>951</td>
      <td>this is the third description</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: is also strange that the col-xs-10 is not taken into consideration, despite bootstrap presence